# How to integrate JFrog Artifactory with XLDeploy using AzureDevOps Pipeline and preferably using the classic UI instead of the YAML way?

Tags: java, azure-devops

As per the requirement of the problem, the workflow is user commits something on the GitHub Enterprise repo, that triggers a Maven build task(considering a Java Springboot Project as per the usecase) and uploads the artifact with the specific version using ArtifactoryUpload task to the correct artifact repo and with the specific war file version, after this how do I deploy the same war file on XLdeploy? Additionally, I am working on a POC pipeline with a sample project to achieve the same and donot have much background on devops so any help would be much appreciated!

I have tried to Integrate the Maven Build task and with Artifactory Upload task, to upload the same on JFROG Artifactory but I am not able to connect to XLDeploy.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you have managed to complete the Mave build and artifact generation steps via Azure pipelines. The only requirement is to connect XL Deploy for deployment.

According to the description of the [Azure DevOps extension for XL Deploy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xebialabs.tfs2015-xl-deploy-plugin).

> With this extension, you will be able to deliver artifacts from your build and release pipeline to XL Deploy.

Hope the information would help you with the next deployment.